# Vectorized formula for output layer in a neural network

Tags: performance, matlab, neural-network, vectorization

I have a neural network and want to use the trained neural network to solve for a set of test data. What I am struggling with is writing the formula for the hidden layer and for the output layer. I aim to have a vectorized formula but I will also be happy to implement a loop variation.

Now I believe I have the correct formula for the hidden layer and only need one for the output layer, but would appreciate it anyone confirm that it is the vectorized formula.

```
% Variables
% Xtest test training data
% thetah - trained weights for inputs to hidden layer
% thetao - trained weights for hidden layer to outputs
% ytest - output

htest =   (1 ./ (1 +  exp(-(thetah * Xtest'))))' ; % FORMULA FOR HIDDEN LAYER
ytest = ones(mtest, num_outputs) ; % FORMULA FOR OUTPUT LAYER
```

Comment: Which formula should be confirmed? The expression for ytest in your code just initializes a new matrix filled with ones and is for sure incorrect. Would you post what you've got so far? What is the dimension of your Xtest? Is it one vector or a set of input vectors?

Comment: The htest should be confirm, at the moment the ytest is just a place holder code that will give the correct dimentions, Xtest is 6,7 the rest is 6,6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below you can find both vectorized and loop implementations of the forward propagation. It is possible, that your input data have to be adapted to the code below, because of different notations and the way you store data in your matrices.

You need to add a bias unit to both input and hidden layer.

In order to simplify the work on the implementation and debugging I took some data from the open source [machine learning repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) and trained the network for [the wine classification task](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine).

- [Xtest](http://it-skills.su/sosamples/ml/wine_files/Xtest.mat) - input data [178x13]
- [y](http://it-skills.su/sosamples/ml/wine_files/y.mat) - output class [178x1]
- [thetah](http://it-skills.su/sosamples/ml/wine_files/thetah.mat) - parameters of the hidden layer [15x14]
- [thetao](http://it-skills.su/sosamples/ml/wine_files/thetao.mat) -
  parameters of the output layer [3x16]

The network separates the input data with rate 97.7%

Here is the code:

```
function [] = nn_fp()

    load('Xtest.mat'); %input data 178x13
    load('y.mat'); %output data 178x1
    load('thetah.mat'); %Parameters of the hidden layer 15x14
    load('thetao.mat'); %Parameters of the output layer 3x16

    predict_simple(Xtest, y, thetah, thetao); 

    predict_vectorized(Xtest, y, thetah, thetao); 
end

function predict_simple(Xtest, y, thetah, thetao)

    mtest = size(Xtest, 1); %number of input examples
    n = size(Xtest, 2); %number of features
    hl_size = size(thetah, 1); %size of the hidden layer (without the bias unit)
    num_outputs = size(thetao, 1); %size of the output layer

    %add a bias unit to the input layer
    a1 = [ones(mtest, 1) Xtest]; %[mtest x (n+1)]

    %compute activations of the hidden layer
    z2 = zeros(mtest, hl_size); %[mtest x hl_size] 
    a2 = zeros(mtest, hl_size); %[mtest x hl_size]

    for i=1:mtest
        for j=1:hl_size
            for k=1:n+1
                z2(i, j) = z2(i, j) + a1(i, k)*thetah(j, k);
            end

            a2(i, j) = sigmoid_simple(z2(i, j));
        end
    end

    %add a bias unit to the hidden layer
    a2 = [ones(mtest, 1) a2]; %[mtest x (hl_size+1)]

    %compute activations of the output layer
    z3 = zeros(mtest, num_outputs); %[mtest x num_outputs]
    h = zeros(mtest, num_outputs); %[mtest x num_outputs]

    for i=1:mtest
        for j=1:num_outputs
            for k=1:hl_size+1
                z3(i, j) = z3(i, j) + a2(i, k)*thetao(j, k);
            end

            h(i, j) = sigmoid_simple(z3(i, j)); %the hypothesis
        end
    end

    %calculate predictions for each input example based on the maximum term
    %of the hypothesis h
    p = zeros(size(y));

    for i=1:mtest
        max_ind = 1;
        max_value = h(i, 1);
        for j=2:num_outputs
            if (h(i, j) > max_value)
                max_ind = j;
                max_value = h(i, j);
            end
        end

        p(i) = max_ind;
    end

    %calculate the success rate of the prediction
    correct_count = 0;
    for i=1:mtest
        if (p(i) == y(i))
            correct_count = correct_count + 1;
        end
    end

    rate = correct_count/mtest*100;

    display(['simple version rate:', num2str(rate)]);
end

function predict_vectorized(Xtest, y, thetah, thetao)

    mtest = size(Xtest, 1); %number of input examples

    %add a bias unit to the input layer
    a1 = [ones(mtest, 1) Xtest];

    %compute activations of the hidden layer
    z2 = a1*thetah';
    a2 = sigmoid_universal(z2);

    %add a bias unit to the hidden layer
    a2 = [ones(mtest, 1) a2];

    %compute activations of the output layer
    z3 = a2*thetao';
    h = sigmoid_universal(z3); %the hypothesis

    %calculate predictions for each input example based on the maximum term
    %of the hypothesis h
    [~,p] = max(h, [], 2);
    %calculate the success rate of the prediction
    rate = mean(double((p == y))) * 100;
    display(['vectorized version rate:', num2str(rate)]);
end

function [ s ] = sigmoid_simple( z )
    s = 1/(1+exp(-z));
end

function [ s ] = sigmoid_universal( z )
    s = 1./(1+exp(-z));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `Xtest` has dimensions `N by M` where N is the number of examples and M is the number of features, `thetah` is a `M by H1` matrix where H1 is the number of hidden layers in the first layer and `thetao` is a `H1 by O` matrix where O is the number of output classes you do the following:

```
a1 = Xtest * thetah; 
z1 = 1 / (1 + exp(-a1)); %Assuming you are using sigmoid units

a2 = z1 * thetao;
z2 = softmax(a2);
```

Read more about softmax [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function).